# How to revise or improve an existed classifier using extra labeled data

Tags: machine-learning

I trained classifiers using co-training, so now I have a machine learning model.

I have some new labeled data. Can I use this new data to revise and improve my classifiers? In this way, hope to make a self-calibrated model.

Comment: where do you get the new labels from? The classifier itself, applied to unlabeled data?

Comment: This is for air quality inference. New labels are real time data from air quality monitoring station. The classifier is applied to predict the quality in the areas not covered by stations.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question generically because you didn't specify neither software nor model you used. Still, many models in machine learning support so called online learning where you obtain the data in small batches (up to 1 sample) and train your model as you go. Or, you can always refit the model on the new dataset.

Comment: Cleaned up grammar to make the question easier to read/understand.